# How to check field comp_status from table companies while login in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, join

I have two tables users (child-table) and companies (parent-table) whose id is defined as foreign key into users. How to do it using join in laravel? While a user of a company logins into the system first company-status must be checked whether the company is active or not; if it is not active the users should not be able to login - status if 0 and 1. I tried a lot and searched in google but could not manage to solve.
Please help me thank you in advance dear developers.

Comment: Assuming you have the correct relations defined in your models, use `auth()->user()->company->status`.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the authenticated method in your Auth/LoginController.php:

```php
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if ($user->company()->where('status', 0)->exists()) {
        Auth::logout();

        return back()->withErrors(['common' => trans('auth.blocked')]);
    }
}
```

This function gets executed automatically after the user has been successfully logged in your application from the LoginController.
If the logged in user has a company whose status is 0, then the user is logged out and you will sent to the previous page with an error

Comment: If that solved your issue do not forget to mark the answer as correct